# blinking LED's without a delay not working

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a problem with my arduino project. It's supposed to have two modes: normal and hazard. The switching between those two is handles by a visual studio form. The blinking leds for the normal mode work just fine but when I tried switching to the hazard mode they blink very dimly. In the hazard mode the red, yellow and blue leds have to blink at the same time. My code makes it so that only the red led is working properly. I'm guessing it has something to do with me using the other two in the normal mode.

```c
void loop() {

  unsigned long currentMillisYellow = millis();
  unsigned long currentMillisBlue = millis();
  unsigned long currentMillisRed = millis();
  unsigned long currentMillisGreen = millis();

  int steerAngle = map(analogRead(Potentiometer), 0, 1024, -100, 100);




  //..........................................................normal state blinking


  if (rightCounter > 0 && steerAngle > 0 && state == NormalState) {
    if (currentMillisBlue - previousMillisBlue > blinkIntervalBlue) {
      previousMillisBlue = currentMillisBlue;

      ledBlueState = !ledBlueState;
      digitalWrite(ledBlue, ledBlueState);
    }
  } else {
    rightCounter = 0;
    digitalWrite(ledBlue, LOW);
  }



  if (leftCounter > 0 && steerAngle < 0 && state == NormalState) {
    if (currentMillisYellow - previousMillisYellow > blinkIntervalYellow) {
      previousMillisYellow = currentMillisYellow;

      ledYellowState = !ledYellowState;
      digitalWrite(ledYellow, ledYellowState);
    }
  } else {
    leftCounter = 0;
    digitalWrite(ledYellow, LOW);
  }


  //..........................................................hazard state blinking


  if (state == HazardState) {                                                     //why is the led brightness so low? (needs to be fixed)
    if (currentMillisYellow - previousMillisYellow > blinkIntervalYellow) {
      previousMillisYellow = currentMillisYellow;

      ledYellowState = !ledYellowState;
      digitalWrite(ledYellow, ledYellowState);
    }
  }


  if (state == HazardState) {
    if (currentMillisBlue - previousMillisBlue > blinkIntervalBlue) {
      previousMillisBlue = currentMillisBlue;

      ledBlueState = !ledBlueState;
      digitalWrite(ledBlue, ledBlueState);
    }
  }


  if (state == HazardState) {
    if (currentMillisRed - previousMillisRed > blinkIntervalRed) {
      previousMillisRed = currentMillisRed;

      ledRedState = !ledRedState;
      digitalWrite(ledRed, ledRedState);
    }
  }
```

Comment: why separate currentMillis? in else case to normal state you turn the LEDs off

Answer (score 0):

Are your blinkIntervals long enough to produce an adequate delay so that the LED can be seen properly *blinking*? As I understand you are trying to **blink** them, namely turn them on then off for a short period. In that case, you might prefer to define ON and OFF intervals, as done in the second example code from [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/using-millis-for-timing) tutorial.

Additionally, as @Juraj said, your `else` block is turning them off and that could be the reason why you see the dim flashing.

I would define states instead of comparing the state inside the if conditional. Something like:

```
typedef enum {
    NORMAL,
    HAZARD
} Modes;

Modes state = NORMAL;
```

then, in your main loop:

```
if( state == NORMAL){

// execute LEDs blinking

} else if(state == HAZARD){

// execute LEDs blinking

}
```